# What is the conventional way to access instance variables within an object in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, conventions, instance-variables

Consider the following code:

```
class Dog
  attr_accessor :name, :color

  def initialize(name, color)
  end
end
```

Within a Ruby object, is the convention to access the instance variable directly (ie `@name = name`) or to use the setter/getter methods (ie `name = name`)?

The former is more clear to me, but if you implement your own setter/getter methods (eg to increment a class variable at the same time) then you end up having to use both approaches (ie `@name = name ; color = color`).

What's the convention within the Ruby community? How should I write my code to make it clear to others who will read it?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312801/is-there-any-benefit-to-using-getters-setters-inside-a-class-for-its-own-fields and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884715/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-properties-internally

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095034/is-it-in-an-anti-pattern-to-always-use-get-and-set-methods-to-access-a-classs-ow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `name = value` is an error, because that creates a local variable named `name`. You must use `self.name = value`.

As for convention, you can only get away with using `@name` if you can guarantee that the accessors will *always* be lightweight `attr_accessor`s. In all other cases, using `@name` over `self.name` will violate encapsulation and give yourself a headache. You gave the exact reason in your question — if there is extra logic in the getter/setter, you must duplicate it if you access the instance variable directly.

Comment: So the local variable `color` has scope precedence over the method `color`?

Comment: Yes, that one will bite you in the ass for sure.  Every so often I forget the @ sign and spend five minutes wondering what could have gone wrong.

Comment: I'm curious; why do you claim that using self.property_name breaks encapsulation?  If there is logic in the setter I would much prefer to use it rather than duplicating code all over the place.

Comment: @Ed I meant the opposite. I rephrased it a bit.

Comment: Ah, now that makes more sense ;). +1

Answer (score 1):

It would be @name. It's more than just a convention. The @ sign defines the scope of the variable to within an instance of the object of which it's defined.

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is the most conventional way, I believe.

Actually attr_accessor creates two instance methods for read and write. It creates 2 methods like:

```
def color() #getter
  @color
end
```

and

```
def color=(color) #setter
  @color = color
end
```

And something like color = color wont work, because then color will be treated as a local variable if it's found on the left of an assignment. You can use self.color = color though.
Again, if the color is not in the left side of any expression, it'll work fine just like the following:

```
def show_color
  puts color
end
```